# Can't submit text input and file input from one form at the same time

Tags: php, html

I have no problem uploading files with the file inputs, but the text inputs don't even react to my clicking. I tried deleting the file inputs, and they started functioning again. Is there any way to use them in one form at the same time?

```
    <form class="upload-box-content popup-animation" action="uploadproject.php"
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="text-block">
            <input type="text" name="project-name" placeholder="Название проекта">
            <input type="text" name="authors" placeholder="Автор(ы) проекта">
            <input type="text" name="supervisor" placeholder="Куратор проекта">
            <input type="text" name="faculty" placeholder="Кафедра">
        </div>

        <div class="upload-tp-block">
            <input type="file" name="textfile">
            <input type="file" name="ppfile">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
```

Here's the uploadproject.php code. I must say that I'm not using the data from the text inputs right now (can't even input a thing after all).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Getting file and all file variables
    $textfile = $_FILES['textfile'];
    $textfilename = $_FILES['textfile']['name'];
    $textfileTmpName = $_FILES['textfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $textfileSize = $_FILES['textfile']['size'];
    $textfileType = $_FILES['textfile']['type'];
    $textfileError = $_FILES['textfile']['error'];

    $ppfile = $_FILES['ppfile'];
    $ppfilename = $_FILES['ppfile']['name'];
    $ppfileTmpName = $_FILES['ppfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $ppfileSize = $_FILES['ppfile']['size'];
    $ppfileType = $_FILES['ppfile']['type'];
    $ppfileError = $_FILES['ppfile']['error'];
    //Getting file extensions
    $textfileExt = explode('.', $textfilename);
    $ppfileExt = explode('.', $ppfilename);
    //Make it lowercase so JPG turn into jpg, and get the extension itself
    $textfileActualExt = strtolower(end($textfileExt));
    $ppfileActualExt = strtolower(end($ppfileExt));

    //Allowed extensions
    $textallowed = array('docx', 'doc', 'txt', 'text', 'pdf');
    $ppallowed = array('ppt', 'pptx');

    if (in_array($textfileActualExt, $textallowed) && 
        in_array($ppfileActualExt, $ppallowed)) {
        if ($textfileError === 0 && $ppfileError === 0) {
            if ($textfileSize < 20000000 && $ppfileSize < 20000000) {
                $textfileDestination = 'uploads/'.$textfilename;
                $ppfileDestination = 'uploads/'.$ppfilename;
                move_uploaded_file($textfileTmpName, $textfileDestination);
                move_uploaded_file($ppfileTmpName, $ppfileDestination);
                header("Location: main.php?upload=success");    
            }
        } else {
            echo "Couldn't upload your file".$textfileError.$ppfileError;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Wrong extension boi";
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Can't find a `Submit` button...

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it.

Comment: send your php code lets see

Comment: Form is pretty standard and should work. Any associated jQuery or javascript?

Comment: "the text inputs don't even react to my clicking"...Seems to work fine...demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ctmj6L73/ (tested in Chrome). So if that is happening, it's caused by something else not shown here, e.g. some JavaScript or faulty CSS maybe. Use your Developer Tools in the browser to take a look.

Comment: No associated JS or CSS. Might be a problem on my side, since it works according to ADyson.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently had some div issues. CSS after all. Thanks for your cooperation.